# Как выбрать и получить данные при парсе в Python?

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

Как сделать запрос, если в одном классе допустим несколько `<a href>` как выбрать тот который мне нужен? Пытаюсь из `<div>` класса `content_product_catalog_list_item_picture` забрать ссылку `<a href>` на страницу товара, но необходимо выбрать определенную, так как после `<div>`, `<a href>` встречается 3 раза

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

HOST = 'https://happywear.ru/'
URL = 'https://happywear.ru/boys/boy-povsednevnaya-odegda/boy-shtani'
HEADERS = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36'
}

def get_html(url, params=''):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r

def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('li', class_='js-catalog-item content_product_catalog_list_item')
    cards = []

    for item in items:
        cards.append(
            {

                'title': item.find('a', class_='content_product_catalog_list_item_info_introtext').get_text(strip=type),
                'title_2': item.find('div', class_='content_product_catalog_list_item_picture').find('a').get_text('href'),
                'title_rub': item.find('div', class_='content_product_catalog_list_item_price__block').get_text(strip=type),
                'card_img': item.find('div', class_='content_product_catalog_list_item_picture').find('img').get('src')
            }
        )
    return cards

html = get_html(URL)
print(get_content(html.text))
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как получить данные при парсе в python?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1265121/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%b2-python)

Answer (score 0):

Ищите по кодовому слову вашу ссылку например:

```
import re
href = soup.find(href=re.compile("boys")) # Для вашего случая ключевое слово должно бить  boys
```